# Get data from Solr to JTable

Tags: java, apache, swing, solr, jtable

I new in Solr. I can add data to Solr from application, but I want to get data from Solr to my Java desktop application.

How can I get data from Solr `("http://localhost:8983/solr")`?

Comment: [whathaveyoutried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solrj](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj) is the easiest way to go. It's the solr java client library.
Add it as a dependency to your project, then write a pojo with all the fields that you want to get back from Solr. Annotate each field with the [solrj `@Field` annotation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#Directly_adding_POJOs_to_Solr), then send your query to Solr like this:

```
SolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer("htp://localhost:8080/solr/core0");
QueryResponse response = solrServer.query(new SolrQuery(query));
List<Pojo> pojos = response.getBeans(Pojo.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use some solr client to requests and handle response data.

But you can do it in simple HTTP GET request if you want to like so:

```
// get all documents
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*
```

If you're using multiple cores, then you probably need to use:

```
// get all documents from core0
http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/select?q=*:*
```

You can read more about solr [common query parameters here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters).